# Chat tableView cells with custom label in swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitableview, livechat, uibubbletableview

I want to make a chat application in swift. Can anyone tell me how to make the UI for chat cells. I know the coding is to be done in cellforRowAtIndexPath, but I don't know the exact way. And the chat cell should be in bubbles? Help me please with sample code?

Comment: You may want to check this library [JSQMessages](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController)

Comment: Thanks for the info. This library is good but I want to create my own chat cells.

Comment: This is very general. Show us some code you have written and where you are stuck or something specific you are having trouble with. SO isn't a free coding service :)

Answer (score 0):

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

```
{
    if (indexPath.section % 2 != 0)
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RightTableViewCell

        if ((array.valueForKey("msgtxt").objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as? String) != nil)
        {
            cell.rightLbl.text = self.array.valueForKey("msgtxt").objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as? String
        }

        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LeftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LeftTableViewCell

        if ((array.valueForKey("msgtxt").objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as? String) != nil)
        {
            cell.leftChatLbl.text = self.array.valueForKey("msgtxt").objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as? String
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

This is what I am doing but it only shows one cell with the same values